# What are some example sentences for 现代汉语词典's first definition of 论证, which means something like "argumentation"?

Tags: meaning, word

Since I'm encountering issues originating from using (insufficiently precise and often incomplete) Chinese-English and English-Chinese dictionaries, I'm trying to make the switch to Chinese-Chinese dictionaries.  In one such dictionary, we find the definition of 论证:

> [论证](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%AE%BA%E8%AF%81) (lùn​zhèng​)
>
> 1. 名：逻辑学指引用论据来证明论题的真实性的论述过程，是由论据推出论题时所使用的推理形式。
> 2. 动：论述并证明：～会。
> 3. 名：立论的根据。
>
> <sup>现代汉语词典 ([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYwOUm.jpg))</sup>

I think I understand 2 and 3 clearly enough: 你**论证**了你的观点 (def. 2; verb), and 你的**论证**很有道理 (def. 3; noun).  The first definition above is a bit more complicated, however.  I feel it means something like the English "argumentation", as an abstract, academic concept.

I feel that perhaps this example sentence from YouDao captures the first definition (although I'm not sure if it's a good example):

> 根据市场和生产厂家的情况，通过**论证**与分析，阐述了配制米的定义和品种种类。

Here I interpret the middle part as "..., by means of argumentation and analysis, ...".  That's the best I've found at this point.

**Question**: What are some example sentences for 现代汉语词典's first definition of 论证?

Comment: if you’re using chinese - chinese dictionary, the 國語辭典 is the authentic, authoritative one you need: http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cbdic/search.htm 

Comment: Although similar, I think 辯證 is "proof through (the knowledge-based) argument/debate" - 辯論證實, and 論證 is "proof through theory (and logic)" - 理論證實.

Comment: Thumb up for the use of Chinese-Chinese dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to dan's answer, the dictionary actually explains that to you.

> **逻辑学指...**
> 逻辑学 - logic
> 指 - refer to

Together, definition 1 means `In logic, the word refers to...`. Although it is clearer to say:

> (论证) 在逻辑学中指...

And you are indeed right on the translation of definition 1. It is an logic terminology means "argument".

Answer (score 0):

[From this website](https://m.zaojv.com/2566704.html)

> 他的 **论证** 严密,无可辩驳。

> 我们写文章要围绕中心论点展开 **论证** 。

> 按照这种 **论证** 的方法,充类至尽,问题也许就可以解决了。

Answer (score 0):

It's the definition in 逻辑学. Usually, you don't have to care about it. Here is the [Baidu reference](https://mip.book118.com/html/2019/0628/5042144214002101.shtm).

Normally, we just focus on definition 2 & 3.